# Split Panda dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a df with a column 'Innings', which contains the following datas :

```
 Innings
[{'InningID': 297503, 'GameID': 47547, 'InningNumber': 1, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 3}, {'InningID': 297504, 'GameID': 47547, 'InningNumber': 2, 'AwayTeamRuns': 2, 'HomeTeamRuns': 2}, {'InningID': 297505, 'GameID': 47547, 'InningNumber': 3, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 2}, {'InningID': 297506, 'GameID': 47547, 'InningNumber': 4, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297507, 'GameID': 47547, 'InningNumber': 5, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297508, 'GameID': 47547, 'InningNumber': 6, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297509, 'GameID': 47547, 'InningNumber': 7, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297510, 'GameID': 47547, 'InningNumber': 8, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297512, 'GameID': 47547, 'InningNumber': 9, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': None}]
[{'InningID': 297511, 'GameID': 47546, 'InningNumber': 1, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297513, 'GameID': 47546, 'InningNumber': 2, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297514, 'GameID': 47546, 'InningNumber': 3, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297515, 'GameID': 47546, 'InningNumber': 4, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297516, 'GameID': 47546, 'InningNumber': 5, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297517, 'GameID': 47546, 'InningNumber': 6, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 3}, {'InningID': 297518, 'GameID': 47546, 'InningNumber': 7, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297519, 'GameID': 47546, 'InningNumber': 8, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 1}, {'InningID': 297520, 'GameID': 47546, 'InningNumber': 9, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 2}]
[{'InningID': 297521, 'GameID': 50022, 'InningNumber': 1, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297522, 'GameID': 50022, 'InningNumber': 2, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297523, 'GameID': 50022, 'InningNumber': 3, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 1}, {'InningID': 297524, 'GameID': 50022, 'InningNumber': 4, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297525, 'GameID': 50022, 'InningNumber': 5, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297526, 'GameID': 50022, 'InningNumber': 6, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297527, 'GameID': 50022, 'InningNumber': 7, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297528, 'GameID': 50022, 'InningNumber': 8, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 2}, {'InningID': 297529, 'GameID': 50022, 'InningNumber': 9, 'AwayTeamRuns': 3, 'HomeTeamRuns': 1}]
[{'InningID': 297530, 'GameID': 47556, 'InningNumber': 1, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297532, 'GameID': 47556, 'InningNumber': 2, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297534, 'GameID': 47556, 'InningNumber': 3, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297536, 'GameID': 47556, 'InningNumber': 4, 'AwayTeamRuns': 2, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297542, 'GameID': 47556, 'InningNumber': 5, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297545, 'GameID': 47556, 'InningNumber': 6, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 1}, {'InningID': 297549, 'GameID': 47556, 'InningNumber': 7, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 2}, {'InningID': 297554, 'GameID': 47556, 'InningNumber': 8, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 1}, {'InningID': 297558, 'GameID': 47556, 'InningNumber': 9, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': None}]
[{'InningID': 297531, 'GameID': 47557, 'InningNumber': 1, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297533, 'GameID': 47557, 'InningNumber': 2, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297535, 'GameID': 47557, 'InningNumber': 3, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297537, 'GameID': 47557, 'InningNumber': 4, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297543, 'GameID': 47557, 'InningNumber': 5, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297546, 'GameID': 47557, 'InningNumber': 6, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297551, 'GameID': 47557, 'InningNumber': 7, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 6}, {'InningID': 297560, 'GameID': 47557, 'InningNumber': 8, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297566, 'GameID': 47557, 'InningNumber': 9, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': None}]
[{'InningID': 297539, 'GameID': 47549, 'InningNumber': 1, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297540, 'GameID': 47549, 'InningNumber': 2, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297544, 'GameID': 47549, 'InningNumber': 3, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297548, 'GameID': 47549, 'InningNumber': 4, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297553, 'GameID': 47549, 'InningNumber': 5, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 5}, {'InningID': 297557, 'GameID': 47549, 'InningNumber': 6, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297561, 'GameID': 47549, 'InningNumber': 7, 'AwayTeamRuns': 3, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297573, 'GameID': 47549, 'InningNumber': 8, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297579, 'GameID': 47549, 'InningNumber': 9, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': None}]
[{'InningID': 297538, 'GameID': 47558, 'InningNumber': 1, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297541, 'GameID': 47558, 'InningNumber': 2, 'AwayTeamRuns': 2, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297547, 'GameID': 47558, 'InningNumber': 3, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297552, 'GameID': 47558, 'InningNumber': 4, 'AwayTeamRuns': 2, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297556, 'GameID': 47558, 'InningNumber': 5, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 5}, {'InningID': 297562, 'GameID': 47558, 'InningNumber': 6, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297568, 'GameID': 47558, 'InningNumber': 7, 'AwayTeamRuns': 2, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297577, 'GameID': 47558, 'InningNumber': 8, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297584, 'GameID': 47558, 'InningNumber': 9, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}]
[{'InningID': 297550, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 1, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297555, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 2, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297559, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 3, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 2}, {'InningID': 297567, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 4, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297569, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 5, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297578, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 6, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297583, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 7, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297587, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 8, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297591, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 9, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297594, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 10, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297597, 'GameID': 47548, 'InningNumber': 11, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 1}]
[]
[{'InningID': 297564, 'GameID': 47553, 'InningNumber': 1, 'AwayTeamRuns': 2, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297572, 'GameID': 47553, 'InningNumber': 2, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297574, 'GameID': 47553, 'InningNumber': 3, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 1}, {'InningID': 297580, 'GameID': 47553, 'InningNumber': 4, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297586, 'GameID': 47553, 'InningNumber': 5, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297590, 'GameID': 47553, 'InningNumber': 6, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297596, 'GameID': 47553, 'InningNumber': 7, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297599, 'GameID': 47553, 'InningNumber': 8, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297603, 'GameID': 47553, 'InningNumber': 9, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 2}]
[{'InningID': 297563, 'GameID': 47555, 'InningNumber': 1, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297570, 'GameID': 47555, 'InningNumber': 2, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 1}, {'InningID': 297575, 'GameID': 47555, 'InningNumber': 3, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 5}, {'InningID': 297582, 'GameID': 47555, 'InningNumber': 4, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 3}, {'InningID': 297588, 'GameID': 47555, 'InningNumber': 5, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 3}, {'InningID': 297593, 'GameID': 47555, 'InningNumber': 6, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297595, 'GameID': 47555, 'InningNumber': 7, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 0}, {'InningID': 297598, 'GameID': 47555, 'InningNumber': 8, 'AwayTeamRuns': 1, 'HomeTeamRuns': 2}, {'InningID': 297601, 'GameID': 47555, 'InningNumber': 9, 'AwayTeamRuns': 0, 'HomeTeamRuns': None}]
```

I need to split the innings columns into many (number can differ line from line...). 
I've tried the explode function, not working, either that the split because of the random number of fields.

The best will be to create new colums, for example :

```
InningID1 : xxx, InningNumber1: x, AwayTeamsRuns1: x, HomeTeamRuns1: x, InningID2 : xxx, InningNumber2: x, AwayTeamsRuns2: x, HomeTeamRuns2: x etc...
```

I don't care about the GameId because I already have this information in the same line of my df.

Any suggestions ?

Many thanks

Geoffrey

Comment: `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in df["Innings"]])`?

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, first clean up the data, replace ' with ", and convert None to "None", and then loop through the DataFrame, convert json string to dict, use `json_normalize` to convert the dict to DataFrame and finally `concat` them:

```
df['Innings'] = df['Innings'].str.replace("\'", '"')
df['Innings'] = df['Innings'].str.replace("None", '"None"')
dfs = []
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    j_str = df.loc[i]['Innings']
    x = json.loads(j_str)
    dfs.append(pd.json_normalize(x))

df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=['index'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    InningID  GameID  InningNumber  AwayTeamRuns HomeTeamRuns
0     297503   47547             1             0            3
1     297504   47547             2             2            2
2     297505   47547             3             0            2
3     297506   47547             4             0            0
4     297507   47547             5             0            0
..       ...     ...           ...           ...          ...
87    297588   47555             5             0            3
88    297593   47555             6             0            0
89    297595   47555             7             1            0
90    297598   47555             8             1            2
91    297601   47555             9             0         None
```

Comment: Not sure if this was what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi,
this will split my Inning column into a new DF no ?

Actually what I want is to drop my initial Innings column, and replace it by several, depends on how many Innings I have in this line.
For example, if I have 9 innings on it, I would require 9 columns suffixed with an _ID (_1 to _9)
Not sure if I'm clear

Comment: Can you paste a sample of what you expect as output? In a table format?

Comment: What I have :
[{'InningID': 297503  'GameID': 47547  'InningNumber': 1  'AwayTeamRuns': 0  'HomeTeamRuns': 3}  {'InningID': 297504  'GameID': 47547  'InningNumber': 2  'AwayTeamRuns': 2  'HomeTeamRuns': 2}

Requested (note that fields are suffixed with the InningID associated) :

[{'InningID_1': 297503    'AwayTeamRuns_1': 0  'HomeTeamRuns_1': 3}  {'InningID': 297504    'AwayTeamRuns_2': 2  'HomeTeamRuns_2': 2}

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want it that way? You can't use a DataFrame properly anymore with that output.

Comment: actually I want all stats to be in the same df, to be able to dump it as a csv file

Comment: I would say the above solution is perfect for a csv, its all in one DataFrame but I'm not sure what the end product is supposed to be like.

Comment: Add to replace the str by replace only for the None
`df['Innings'] = df['Innings'].replace("None", '"None"', inplace=True)`

And got a key error while entering the loop
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/geoffrey/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 133, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
 [...]
KeyError: 0`

Comment: I converted your dict to json first, so this replace had to be done, since None is a string

Comment: Sorry man, can't help any further. This is a possible solution, it works for me, try to debug and see where it went wrong for you.

Comment: yeah thanks, I think the replace work well, but issue seems to be located on the for loop. I will try to figure how to deal with that and post the solution here

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a great opportunity to use `DictVectorizer`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vectorizer = DictVectorizer()
dicts = df.explode("Innings")["Innings"]
data = vectorizer.fit_transform(dicts).todense()
innings_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=vectorizer.feature_names_)
```

Missing keys would be automatically populated with zeros, make sure that's the behaviour you want.

And now you can concat/join `innings_df` with your original dataframe (`df`) if you'd like

Comment: Not working :( 
   data = vectorizer.fit_transform(dicts).todense()
  File "/Users/geoffrey/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/_dict_vectorizer.py", line 228, in fit_transform
    return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
  File "/Users/geoffrey/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/_dict_vectorizer.py", line 165, in _transform
    for f, v in x.items():
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: it seems like one of the rows contains a `float`, and not a `dict` like you posted in your question.

Comment: Do you have `NaN`s in your dataset ? consider applying `.dropna()` or `.fillna`